# Nest js throttler with GraphQL is not working as expected

Tags: graphql, nestjs, express-graphql

```
@Injectable()
export class GqlThrottlerGuard extends ThrottlerGuard {
  getRequestResponse(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const gqlCtx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
    const ctx = gqlCtx.getContext();
    return { req: ctx.req, res: ctx.res };
  }
}
```

Here I am getting only *req* from *ctx*, *res* is undefined. I am using GraphQL with express in nestjs.

This is how my context object looks like before creating a GqlExecutionContext:

```
    ExecutionContextHost {
  args: [
    undefined,
    { id: 2 },
    { req: [IncomingMessage] },
    {
      fieldName: 'user',
      fieldNodes: [Array],
      returnType: User!,
      parentType: Query,
      path: [Object],
      schema: [GraphQLSchema],
      fragments: [Object: null prototype] {},
      rootValue: undefined,
      operation: [Object],
      variableValues: {},
      cacheControl: [Object]
    }
  ],
  constructorRef: [class UsersResolver],
  handler: [Function: findOne],
  contextType: 'graphql'
}
```

**Error:**

```
[Nest] 30284  - 08/01/2022, 12:54:25 am   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read property 'ip' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ip' of undefined
    at ThrottlerGuard.getTracker (C:\Users\Mahesh\OneDrive\Desktop\graphql-server\node_modules\@nestjs\throttler\dist\throttler.guard.js:95:16)
```

Comment: GraphQL with express or Fastify? What does your [graphql context option](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/apollo-server/#context) look like?

Comment: And how do you have this guard bound? You aren't double binding are you?

Comment: Hi Jay McDoniel, I have updated my question have a look at and Im bounding guard in app module only. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I got the following error message

```
cannot read property 'header' of undefined
```

I think the main problem comes from the ctx.res which is undefined.
To resolved the problem I used the following code:

```
ctx.req.res
```

In your case it should be:

```
@Injectable()
export class GqlThrottlerGuard extends ThrottlerGuard {
getRequestResponse(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const gqlCtx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
    const ctx = gqlCtx.getContext();
    return { req: ctx.req, res: ctx.req.res };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have added the req, res to the context in `GraphQLModule.forRoot()` So after creating Graphql execution context I am able to get the required data in the return statement `{ req: ctx.req, res: ctx.res }`.

```
GraphQLModule.forRoot({
  autoSchemaFile: 'src/graphql-schema.gql',
  context: ({ req, res }) => ({ req, res }),
}),
```