# Cannot read property 'ip' of undefined when testing rate limiting on nest.js

Tags: nestjs, rate-limiting

So I have the following configured in my nest.js graphql applicaiton, which seems to be working;

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ThrottlerModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => ({
        ttl: config.get('THROTTLE_TTL'),
        limit: config.get('THROTTLE_LIMIT'),
      }),
    }),
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: ThrottlerGuard,
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

but when I try to load test against my local server, the dropped requests all raise the following error

```
[Nest] 3177  - 2022-09-18T16:25:36.188Z   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read property 'ip' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ip' of undefined
```

Why is the request handler not able to capture IP address? Is it b/c its going through one localhost to another?

Comment: Did you follow [the steps for using GraphQL in the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/rate-limiting#graphql)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As the documentation shows](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/rate-limiting#graphql) the `ThrottlerGuard` needs to be extended to make the `getRequestResponse` method return the correct values so that the `ip` and `headers` objects can be referenced properly.

```js
@Injectable()
export class GqlThrottlerGuard extends ThrottlerGuard {
  getRequestResponse(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const gqlCtx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
    const ctx = gqlCtx.getContext();
    return { req: ctx.req, res: ctx.res };
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked, but where does it say that this is needed to make the `getRequestResponse` return correct values so that ip and header objects can be referenced properly.

Comment: I literally linked it. It doesn't explicitly say _why_ the `getRequestResponse` method needs to be overwritten, but it should be rather implied that there are things on the `request` and `response` objects that are being read

Comment: This solution caused "cannot read property 'header' of undefined" for me. This other solution fixed it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73440076/3470632

Comment: @KevinWheeler it probbaly depends on what your `context` property for the `GraphQLModule`'s options looks like. For express, it should be `context: ({ req, res }) => ({ req, res })`. If you're using fastify it's `context: (req, res) => ({ req, res })` if I recall correctly